# Let ABCDEF be a regular hexagon

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let $ABCDEF$ be a regular hexagon. Points $P$ and $Q$ on tangents to its circumcircle at $A$ and $D$ respectively such that $PQ$ touches the minor arc $EF$ of this circle. Prove that the angle between $PB$ and $QC$
is $30^o$.

Comment: Try drawing a diagram. It will be helpful.

Comment: I added an image that I think it would be helpful @SS_C4

Comment: Yes, and apparently, the angle is already found to be $30$ degrees?

Comment: yes prove that @SS_C4

Comment: @Zhuxing where did you find this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(1) $ABP$~$DQC$ such that $\angle DCQ=\angle ABP$. Proof:

$$\angle CDQ=\angle BAP=150^o$$ due to contruction. Now, it sufficient to show that two triangles are similar if they have a common angle and the ratio of its sides are equal, i.e. $$\frac{AB}{DQ}=\frac{AP}{CD}$$
To show it we observe that $OAP$~$ODQ$ where $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABCDEF$.
Since $APTO$ and $ODQT$ are cyclic we have the following: $$\angle APO=\angle OAT$$ $$\angle QDO=\angle QTD$$ $$\angle OAT=\angle QTD$$ Because $QT=QD$, $OA=OT$ and since $\angle TOA=\angle TQB$ the above is shown.
So we have showed that $APO$~$QDO$ we have: $$\frac{AP}{OD}=\frac{AO}{DQ}$$ Now, $OD=CD$ and $AO=AB$ because it is well known that the sides of a regular hexagon is the same of the radius from the circumscribed circle.

Hence we have proved the proposition.

Now lets call $\angle APB=x$ and $\angle APT=y$. $$\angle CQD=30-x$$ $$\angle DQT=180-y$$
$$\angle GQP=\angle DQT-\angle DQC=180-y-(30-x)$$ $$\angle GPQ=\angle APT-\angle APB=y-x$$ $$\angle PGQ=180-(\angle GPQ+\angle GQP)=180-(y-x+180-y-(30-x))=30^o$$

And it's done!

Comment: Why do you think that $AP$ has to equal $r$?

Comment: Well I miss understand the problem's statement I thought that $PQ$ touches the mid point of the arc $EF$, I'll provide a new solution

Comment: I think you mean $ABP$ ~ $DQC$, and (especially!) $OTPA$ ~ $QTOD$.

Comment: What do you mean with especially

Comment: It is very obvious that $OTPA$~$OTQD$ if wanted I can write a proof but I don't have time now I'll do it later

Comment: When you say $OTPS$ ~ $OTQD$, you are implying that the points $P$ and $S$ correspond to the points $Q$ and $D$ in the similarity mapping. Whereas in fact we have $O$ ~ $Q$, $T$ ~ $T$, $P$ ~ $O$, and  $A$ ~ $D$. I say "especially" because this confused me when I first read it.

Comment: So you agree with my solution ?

Comment: Not as it stands. Your similarity statements are wrong.

Comment: I really don't see what you are saying

Comment: thats not correct

Comment: @Zhuxing I've revised the solution so please if it is wrong tell me and also tell me WHY? is it wrong THANKS!